# Can nodejs read project file in Electron application?

Tags: node.js, electron

Can nodejs read project file in Electron project?

I want to use nodejs read source code in my Electron project,

```
// electron-src/index.ts
import fs from 'fs'
...

ipcMain.on('searchSourcecode', (event: IpcMainEvent, message: any) => {
  console.log(message)

  fs.readFile("./index.ts", "utf8",function(err, data){
    console.log(err);
    console.log(data);

    event.returnValue = data 

  });


})
```

[image]

this get error:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './index.ts'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: './index.ts'
}
```

---

and before try to implement this function in Electron, I have tried to read source code in nodejs, it success:

```
var fs = require('fs')

const search = () => {
  fs.readFile("./myComp01/index.tsx", "utf8", function(err, data){
    console.log(data);
  });
}

search()
```

so, why in my Electron project it cannot do it?

Comment: Most-likely the path is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You could use nodejs module `path` to get the absolute path:

```
import fs from 'fs'
const path = require('path');
...

ipcMain.on('searchSourcecode', (event: IpcMainEvent, message: any) => {
  console.log(message)

  const currentDir = __dirname;
  const filePath = path.join(currentDir, './index.ts');


  fs.readFile(filePath, "utf8",function(err, data){
    console.log(err);
    console.log(data);

    event.returnValue = data 
  });
})
```